# Can we give 2 different values to a constant in java?

Tags: java

I know it doesn't make any sens.. but I'm new, and I have a project for class (java).

Here is the thing. We must create a program that prints a receipt (pizza store).
Theres 4 different combo named : combo 1, combo 2, combo 3, combo 4. And each one has its own value. But combo 1 = 1 Pizza large 14”, 12 chicken wings, and 1 medium fries. Combo 2 = ... , combo 3 =.. You get the point.

Can we say that:

```
COMBO_1 = 24.99 AND COMBO_1 =  1 Pizza large 14”, 12 chicken wings, and 1 medium fries
```

?

Comment: There is almost definitely a better solution to this problem. Please explain your problem in detail, and refer to [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom Object maybe called `Combo`. Then the `Combo` object would have two properties:

1. Description
2. Price

You create the `Combo` object by passing in the `Description` and `Price` as parameters. Then you would add a `getDescription()` and `getPrice()` method so you can access the data of the class.

This is the basics of creating a custom object.

```
public class Combo
{
    private String description;
    private double price;

    public Combo(String desctiption, double price)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDesctiption()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    ...
}
```

I'll let you fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner, then you might not have learned classes yet.

The alternative is using arrays.

```
String[] orders = new String[4];
orders[0] = "1 Pizza large 14\", 12 chicken wings, and 1 medium fries;24.99";
// TODO: set orders 1..3
```

Then when you print the receipt you can do

```
for (String o : orders) {
   String parts = o.split(";"); // used ; because there are commas within the data
   String description = parts[0];
   String price = parts[1];
   // TODO: print them
}
```

Otherwise, you would be stuck with individual variables

```
String combo1Description;
int combo1Price;
...
```

Which is not easy to loop over